So in separate ways they work, together they don't work, why?
<div class="menumovel"><-- 2º but its inside this one -->
<div class="mmovel"><!-- 1ª this one i need to close -->
<p class="mfechar">X</p>
<ul>
    <li>Logo</li>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <li class="quemsou">Olá <?php 
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo $current_user->user_login;
?></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); ?>">Sair</a></li>
    <?php else: ?>
    <li class="clickentrar">Entrar</li>
<?php endif; ?>
    <li>Registar</li>
    <li>Serviços</li>
    <li>Sobre</li>
    <li>Area Cliente</li>
    <li>Contatos</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(".mmovel").hide();
$(".menumovel").click(function(){
    $(".mmovel").show();
});
$(".mfechar").click(function(){
    $(".mmovel").hide();
});

</script>
<style>
.mfechar{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:60px;
    right:30px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.menumovel{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    top:60px;
    right:30px;
    
}
.menumovel::before{
    content:"☰";
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.mmovel{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:999;
    background:green;
}
</style>

So in separate ways they work, but together they don't work, why?
to have an idea I want a popup window with a button to open and close.
many thanks
an answer to see what I'm doing wrong
"The problem I think was the div I want to close its inside an absolute div with just 50px width and height, and i think the button its stuck there"

Not clear what you mean about separate ways, maybe add an example along with the HTML. On the editor toolbar, there is a <> icon to create a stacksippet, like a fiddle. The only HTML that is needed is what is within the <body tag. Can choose jquery from the left side of the page.

Make reproductible exemple please...

The mistake in this case was in html look i will show it's a div incide other one that c turn impossible the button to work see 

so sorry guys for w'ont let the entire code in the post but think dont needed so my html its wrong but i think i know why so I will put my entire code in the post.
